# Area of Cylinders

Tags: geometry

If a gallon of paint covers 225 square feet, how many full gallons of paint must be purchased to paint the exterior of this building? [image]
I've did lateral area of the cylinder and the surface area of the sphere and then cut it in half since it's only half the sphere, my answer was 425 gallons but my classmates say they got 8 gallons I don't understand what I'm doing wrong please help!

Comment: Can you show your calculations?  How did you find the lateral area of the cylinder and surface area of the sphere?

Comment: The lateral area of the cylinder is 2(pi)(r)h and for the sphere is 4 (pi)r^2, so I found both of them and added it together and once I times it by pi I get 1627 square feet and I subtracted 225 and then cover it to gallons and got 425 I don't know where I went wrong

Comment: Why did u subtract 225, you should have divided by 225

Comment: What ^^ said.  Your area calculation is correct (to the nearest square foot).

Comment: Could you recall what a gallon is for dummies using stupid metric system ($>90$ % of humans and 99.9% of scientsts) ?

Answer (score 1):

The surface area you are after is:

\begin{align}
A = \frac{1}{2}A_{\text{sphere}} + A_{\text{wall of cylinder}}
\end{align}

We know that
\begin{align}
A_{\text{sphere}} &= 4\pi r^2 = 4\pi\cdot7^2 = 615.75\\
A_{\text{wall of cylinder}} &= 2\pi r h = 2\pi\cdot 7\cdot30=1319.47
\end{align}

So plugging this into the equation for $A$, we obtain
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{1}{2}A_{\text{sphere}} + A_{\text{wall of cylinder}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot615.75+1319.47\\
&=1627.31\text{ sq. feet}
\end{align}

Now, since each gallon covers 225 sq. feet we divide to get the number of gallons we require: $\frac{1627.31}{225} = 7.23$. So, $8$ full gallons must be purchased.

Comment: Keep in mind that the bottom of the cylinder doesn't need to be painted.  It's on the ground.

Comment: And this is why you should never hire a mathematician to paint a building!

Comment: @Claycrusher First lift the building off the ground, thus reducing the problem to the full-cylinder problem already solved...

Comment: Y'all are killing me :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the full surface area of the building we must find the lateral area of the cylinder and the surface area of the hemisphere (excluding the bottom), as you said.  The formula for lateral area of the cylinder is $2\pi rh$ and the formula for the surface area of the hemisphere is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4\pi r^2=2\pi r^2$.  Plugging in numbers, we get the lateral area of the cylinder to be $2\pi\cdot 7\cdot 30 \approx 1319$ square feet and the surface area of the hemisphere to be $3\pi \cdot 7^2 \approx 308$ square feet.  The sum is $1319+308=1627$ square feet.  To convert to gallons, we divide by $225$ since that is how many square feet one gallon of paint will cover.  The result is $\frac{1627}{225} \approx 7.23$ gallons.  Since we must buy full gallons we round up to $8$ gallons.

Answer (score 0):

The surface area of the sphere is $4\pi (49)$ and the area surface of the cylinder is $(2\pi (7)(30))$ so indeed you need to cut the sphere in half and the total surface area is $2 \pi (7(30) + 49)= 2\pi (259)$. Notice that 259 is slightly bigger than 225 but $\pi < 4$. Doing the exact calculations you obtain that $2\pi (259) \leq 8(225)$ so 8 gallons are enough.